# how can i hide the part of url using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla, url-rewriting

I am trying to remove the part from my url here is the url **"http://example.com/custom_joomla_template-2.5.6/about-us/portfolio/itemlist/category/3-category-2"**

Now I want to remove "itemlist/category/" from the url so that url can be look link **"http://example.com/custom_joomla_template-2.5.6/about-us/portfolio/3-category-2"**

I am using default functionality of joomla i.e. SEF urls, I need to simplify it more I am new for the htaccess

Please suggest link for learning how to write rules for .htaccess file

Please help

Comment: You need to edit the router.php really for this functionality in the component

Answer (score 0):

Easiest thing is just to make a menu link somewhere that goes directly to category-2. That will set up the url correctly. It will also get rid of the 3-